# Python: Cannot Run Script Outside of PyCharm (ImportError)

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror

I am attempting to run a script that I have finished writing without having to launch PyCharm every time I run it.

However, I receive the following error when trying to run it from my command-line in `Windows 10`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stuff\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    import irc.bot
ImportError: No module named irc.bot
```

My folder structure to get to irc.bot looks like:

```
main folder
--venv
----lib
------site-packages
--------irc
----------bot.py
```

I'm fairly certain the issue is the virtual environment configuration, but I'm not sure how to get around that in a batch file to launch my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for python to recognize the module, first enter the virtual environment using the script located at:

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

Comment: Thank you. After a bit more googling of my next issue, it looks like I have it working!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue.

Upgrade the version of pip, wheel and setuptools in your virtualenv and afterwards try to install irc.

Hope that it works.